# Error while updating a table with sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, sequence

I have table `Hash_emp` and a sequence as below

[image: HASH_EMP Table]

Sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE Increment_bY_1 
START WITH 1 
INCREMENT BY 1 
NOMAXVALUE NOCYCLE
CACHE 10;
```

[image: Sequence]

When I am updating the `Employee_id` with the `For` loop, it is throwing an error. Can someone explain what went wrong?

```
declare 
i number;
begin
for i in 2..29  
update hash_emp set EMPLOYEE_ID=INCREMENT_BY_1.nextval where rownum=i; 
end loop;
end;
```

**Error**

> PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "UPDATE" when expecting one of the following:
>
> - & - + / at loop mod remainder rem  ||
>     multiset
>     The symbol "loop" was substituted for "UPDATE" to continue.
>
>   6550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
>           *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error. --------------

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query, no need to use for loop, use the query as it is

```
update hash_emp set EMPLOYEE_ID=INCREMENT_BY_1.nextval where rownum between 2 and 29;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the other answer points out, the FOR LOOP is not needed. But just for completeness, this is why you got the error in the first place. The actual error is cause by a syntax error in the FOR LOOP statement. The [syntax](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/for_loop_statement.htm#LNPLS1515) for a FOR LOOP is:

```
FOR index IN lower_bound .. upper_bound LOOP
  statement;
END LOOP;
```

In your case the first "LOOP" is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that the use of ROWNUM is not necessary. ROWNUM is a pseudo column populated by Oracle only at runtime of a query or command. It only has meaning in the context of that command with its particular predicate and sort, and doesn't have anything to do with the order of data stored on disk or in the table. By specifying ROWNUM without other conditions, you're actually telling Oracle to update whatever *random* rows happen to get returned in positions 2 through 29 of the result set.

If you want to leave the row with an EMPLOYEE_ID value already assigned alone and only update those that are null, use this:

```
update hash_emp set EMPLOYEE_ID=INCREMENT_BY_1.nextval where EMPLOYEE_ID IS NULL;
```